# How a ViewModel communicates with its own View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am developing a WPF MVVM Light application, I want to display some message boxes/dialog boxes or there are some other scenarios where I want my View model to communicate with its view or raise some event on its respective view.

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Messenger class of MVVM Light. It should even have sample by default when you downloa MVVM light. It's something like Messenger.Default.Send(new YourMessageClass()) and you can register listener on View side.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes it works. But it is not consistent. I have a select screen that is containing a button binded to a command in view model, on click on that button, command fires and use Messenger.Default.Send method and 'select screen receives that message and I open a CRUD screen from that message. Now when that CRUD screen tries to send message, it also received by 'select screen' instead of 'CRUD screen.

Comment: It is working fine now, I just have to set Token property along with the message.

Answer (score 1):

The prism framework has a concept of interaction requests to solve this problem. A nice example can be found [here](http://blogs.southworks.net/aadami/2012/05/09/prism-interactionrequest-and-popupmodalwindowaction-for-wpf-applications/) or [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/269364/MVVM-PRISM-Modal-Windows-by-using-Interaction-Requ).

Comment: Thanks but I am bound to stick with MVVM Light for client requirements.

Comment: Well, the trigger action class is part of the .NET framework. the only thing you need is to implement an equivalent to the interaction request class. It's the pattern that is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The responsibility of displaying the popup should not be the ViewModel's responsibility, but a "service that takes care of it for you".

If the "popup window" is a modal like window like a "file open dialog", "file save dialog", message box "ok/cancel" or "yes/no" etc, then I believe that a "service" would be the right choice.  The reason is that the service can be facked/mocked for unit testing.

Also, you can have different implementations of this service based on whatever you want: in debug (r, when the role is of type admin or developer) you have more "verbose" information than in release or regular users, for example.

Now, for "how does a ViewModel communicate to the View", I'm not sure what you mean. Simply add a property on the ViewModel and bind the view to that property.